# Unload dynamic compiled dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain

I have a little problem. First, I have a program, which has a class for compiling assemblies from scripts that could be written inside this program for using programs data. So I can't unload generated assembly. Tried to use AppDomain.Unload, but it shows that file "Scripts.DLL" is busy. I wish you could help. Here's my code.

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IScriptableComponent component = new DummyComponent();

        var compiledAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ScriptsDirectory, CompiledScriptsAssemblyName);
        var scriptFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(ScriptsDirectory, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

        var scriptAssembly = Helper.CompileAssembly(scriptFiles, compiledAssemblyPath);

        var scriptTypes = Helper.GetTypesImplementingInterface(scriptAssembly, typeof(IScript));

        foreach (var scriptType in scriptTypes)
        {
            var script = (IScript)Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType);
            script.Run(component);
        }
    }
```

Helper class:

```
public static Assembly CompileAssembly(string[] sourceFiles, string outputAssemblyPath)
    {

        var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,    
            GenerateInMemory = false,      
            IncludeDebugInformation = false, 
            OutputAssembly = outputAssemblyPath
        };

        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        var result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(compilerParameters, sourceFiles);

        if (result.Errors.HasErrors) throw new Exception("Assembly compilation failed.");
        
        return result.CompiledAssembly;
    }


    public static List<Type> GetTypesImplementingInterface(Assembly assembly, Type interfaceType)
    {
        if (!interfaceType.IsInterface) throw new ArgumentException("Not an interface.", "interfaceType");

        return assembly.GetTypes()
                       .Where(t => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
                       .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You can't unload the main appDomain, you must load your assembly in a secondary appDomain. Also you must create proxies for your classes and your classes must implement MarshalByRef so they don't cross the AppDomain boundaries or the assemblies will be also loaded in the main appDomain (check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091726/The-Nuances-of-Loading-and-Unloading-Assemblies-wi)

Comment: Thanks, i`ve tried this sample https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6a896ca-8905-41fb-8f52-7f39e89c9a91/problem-loading-and-unloading-dynamically-an-assembly-dll-in-c?forum=csharplanguage but it didnt help....